# How can I make this code more concurrent?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I have a piece of code which is similar to the following:

```
final int THREADS = 11;  
BlockingQueue<Future<Long>> futureQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Future<Long>>(THREADS);  
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++, count++) {  
    futureQueue.put(executor.submit(MyRunnable));  
}   
//Use queued results
```

How could I refactor this to make it **more concurrent**? Are there any subtleties I am overseeing here?

**UPDATE:**
Each Runnable is supposed to send a large amount of HTTP request to a server for stress testing.Am I on right track?

Comment: Have you looked at using a load-testing tool, like jMeter? Reinventing the wheel, NIH and all that.

Comment: Have you've seen this? https://github.com/excilys/gatling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

```
static final int THREADS = Runnable.getRuntime().availableProcesses();  

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

List<Future<Long>> futureQueue = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>(end);  
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
    futureQueue.add(executor.submit(new MyRunnable()));
```

You are using a bounded queue and if `end > THREADS` it will just stop.

> Each Runnable is supposed to send a large amount of HTTP request to a server for stress testing.Am I on right track?

In that case I would use the following as your code is IO rather than CPU bound.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

While you might benefit from using NIO if you had more than 1000 threads, this would only make your load tester more efficient, but it would make the code much more complicated.  (If you think this is hard, writing efficient and correct Selector code is *much* harder)

Run the tester on more than one machine would make much more difference.

Comment: `end` is a lot greater than `THREADS`. Perhaps I should have mentioned this but this (each `Runnable`) is supposed to send a large amount of HTTP request to a server for stress testing.Am I on right track?

Comment: What do you mean `if end > THREADS it will just stop.`?

Comment: @Jim I mean you have specifically chosen a collection with a *limited* capacity, and you have chosen the `put` method which blocks whenever the *Blocking*Queue is full. So if you have more tasks than you make the capacity, the queue will fill and it will block.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:So if I change to `add` will it be ok?

Comment: `add` will discard Futures when the queue is full.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:So how is the code you posted improving my situation?Could you help me understand this?

Comment: I only really changed two lines. Used `add` instead of `put` and I use a `List` which is unbounded instead of a bounded queue. Rather than using an arbitrary number of threads, I made the number of threads match the number of logical processors you have so it will always be as concurrent as possible.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:So if `List` is unbounded the `new ArrayList<Future<Long>>(end);` is only to avoid the overhead of doubling on large sizes?

Comment: Correct, given you know how many objects you are going to add, it is a micro-optimisation. You are unlikely to notice the difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:But `ArrayList` is not thread safe.Should I be worry for that?

Comment: Only if you access it from more than one thread. If you are its likely you should restructure your code so this is not the case. IMHO only use thread safe collections which need to be thread safe. Using a thread safe collection when it doesn't need to be can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Using threads doesn't work well in your case. Thread pools work well when you have a CPU intensive job. In your case, you have an IO intensive job - it's not bound by the number of CPUs that you have but by the number of network packets you can send.

In this case, the classes in NIO are your friend. Create hundreds of connections and use [NIO selectors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) to see which one is ready to receive more data.

Using this approach, you don't need threads at all; one CPU core is more than enough to fill even a GBit Ethernet connection (~100MB/s).

**[EDIT]** Of course, you could create hundreds of threads to try to fill the IO channel. But this has some drawbacks:

1. Threads are managed by the OS (or a small helper library). They need memory and each time a thread is switched, the CPU will have to save its state and flush its caches.
2. If a thread does only a small amount of work, thread switching can be more expensive than doing the work.
3. When you use threads, you get all the usual thread synchronization issues.
4. There is no simple way to make sure you have the right amount of threads. If there are too few threads, the IO channel won't be used optimally. If there are too many threads, the channel won't be used optimally because the threads will fight for access for it. In both cases, you can't change this after starting your tests. The system doesn't adapt to the needs.

For tasks like this, a framework like [Akka](http://akka.io/) is much better suited because it avoids all these issues and it's more simple to use than threads.

Comment: "Using threads only helps when you have a CPU intensive job" - that's not quiet true. IO bound application profiles would be helped too. Rather than block waiting for IO, another thread can kick off stuff... http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/recipes/2012/07/12/optimise-the-number-of-threads/

Comment: @Toby: +1 but in this case, even a single CPU core is going to be bored by the job.

Comment: Given the OP doesn't appear to know the difference between a bounded BlockingQueue and a List, I am not sure trying to use NIO Selectors is a good idea. ;)

Comment: `Using threads only helps when you have a CPU intensive job`.This does not seem correct to me.For CPU bound threads, creating more threads makes things worse as threads compete over CPU.For I/O bound tasks creating more threads improves things as the CPU is never idle by threads blocked for I/O

Comment: That's correct but the Java Executor doesn't know when a thread is idle, so it's not going to start another thread when one of the existing threads blocks on IO. That means you'll have to create an executor with many threads - but how many exactly? Also, switching threads is pretty cheap but it's not free. Threads need to be managed somewhere. Not to mention all the synchronization issues that you get for free. Which is why state of the art web servers have abandoned threads (node, vert.x).

Comment: But the executor knows how many threads are running.And the workers executes jobs from the queue.So if a specific task is blocked on I/O it does not matter since as long as the executor can create a thread (<maxThreadSize) a new thread will be created for the task

Comment: It will either create too few or too many threads. There is no way to create more threads when the IO channel isn't filled or reduce threads when the management of the threads starts to take more CPU than the actual tasks. You should really look into a framework like [Akka](http://akka.io/) for things like this.

Comment: Or maybe to put it another way: You can use a truck to drive nails into a wall but a hammer would do a better job.

Comment: When you say `node` you mean `node.js`.I don't know these servers you are referring.What do you mean state of the art?Are they better than `JBoss` or `Tomcat`?

Comment: node===node.js. Define "better", please :-) As a rule of thumb, they can process much more requests per second on the same hardware. They aren't limited by the max. number of threads and the applications aren't subject to strange threading issues like unsynchronized access to shared memory.

Comment: Try this approach: If you have something that needs lots of memory and 100% of the CPU, thread pools are a good solution (depending on the kind of locking that you need). Typical examples: Raytracing, doing math on huge amounts of data in memory. For IO bound tasks (searching data in a database, handling thousands of HTTP requests), threads only get you so far.

Comment: Define better? Well what do you mean then "state of the art"?

Comment: From a developer point of view, some things are more simple with JBoss and some with node.js and some with vert.x. nodes.js and vert.x need less CPU, JBoss can do more things out of the box. If your main goal is processing millions of requests per second, JBoss won't work for you.

Comment: Interesting.Do you have a reference on which server is better for what?

Comment: No. The main problem with the old approach (= J2EE) is that it's pretty bloated and creates a lot of invisible dependencies which eventually kill you as you try to scale. New approaches use actors and avoid threads because of all the drawbacks. But they aren't better as in "absolutely better, no questions asked." There is no silver bullet technology. Each has strengths and weaknesses which is why you should do a serious evaluation of your needs every time you start a new project.

Comment: @AaronDigulla:But it is not clear to me, when you suggest that threads should be used.It sounds like you reject the use of threading all together.But then multicore systems are pretty much wasted.

Comment: Like any tool, threading has it's place, strengths and drawbacks. Solutions like node.js and Akka have demonstrated that non-threaded code can be more efficient and easier to write/maintain than threaded code. And, this is the joke, when you wrote code for these frameworks, they can use threads without you ever noticing.

Comment: PS: Thanks for being so persistent with this topic. It's important to understand all the issues involved.